# wp_insert_post Only creates draft

Tags: wp-insert-post, draft

When I call wp_insert_post() with a post status, it only creates posts with "Draft" status. I've tested it with WordPress built-in statuses and my custom post statuses. But it only creates Draft posts, which I can't trash or delete them from WordPress. Here is my code. Please help.

```
// Prepare to save!
        do_action( 'wpo_frontend_before_save_order', $order_details, $user_details );
        $post = array(
            'post_title'        =>  $order_details['title'],
            'post_author'       =>  get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'         =>  'wp_order',
            'post_status'       =>  'pending'
        );
        $postID = wp_insert_post( $post );
        if ( is_wp_error( $postID ) ) {
            set_transient( 'wpo_new_order_message_' . get_current_user_id(), __( 'There was a problem to register your order. Please try again later', 'wpo' ) );
            return;
        }
```

Comment: It's very likely that this is caused by a plugin. Does this problem occur with all plugins enabled? Could you check your plugin folders for the occurence of "wp_insert_post_data"?

Comment: I never used "wp_insert_post_data", I never hear it before that.

Comment: It might be a *plugin* that's actually hooking into this filter. Please just simply do a search in your plugins folder and post the results here.

Comment: @Ehsaan as a side note, you should try to avoid using `$post` as a variable name, as it's often a global reference to the `WP_Post` object

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code created drafts only is status='pending' make it publish

Like
// Prepare to save!

```
   do_action( 'wpo_frontend_before_save_order', $order_details, $user_details );
     $post = array(
         'post_title'        =>  $order_details['title'],
         'post_author'       =>  get_current_user_id(),
         'post_type'         =>  'wp_order',
         'post_status'       =>  'publish'
     );
     $postID = wp_insert_post( $post );
     if ( is_wp_error( $postID ) ) {
         set_transient( 'wpo_new_order_message_' . get_current_user_id(), __( 'There was a problem to register your order. Please try again later', 'wpo' ) );
         return;
    }
```

Comment: In the example, it uses pending, but he did mention that he tried it with all built in statuses, so he would have tried "publish" too...

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have publish status. I can't use it. I must be used "pending" or "unpayed" or "payed" or "completed"

Comment: publish didn't work. any ideas? is this a WordPress bug or my plugin bug?

Comment: Have your tried with "payed" and "completed"?

Comment: yes TBI. I tested. It doesn't work. Please anyone help me.

Comment: *unpaid vs paid